# Pyspark to scala. String join function on elements after grouping

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have to translate pyspark to scala.
I have a function like this: `lambda x: ';'.join(map(str, x)`.
Then we use

```
our_dataframe.groupBy('column').agg(our_lambda_function(F.collect_set('other_col')))
```

So we group by some column first and then get values as an array of strings. Our lambda function makes a string out of this array.

Example. Instead of

> ### |column|
>
> |[a,b,c]|
> |[d,e,f]|

we want to have

> ### |column|
>
> |a;b;c|
> |d;e;f|

How to make that in scala?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `concat_ws` function to get elements concat with `;`

**`Example:`**

```
df.groupBy(lit(1)).agg(concat_ws(";",collect_set(col("id"))).alias("column")).
select("column").
show(10,false)
//+------+
//|column|
//+------+
//|c;b;a |
//+------+
```